# r/ggplot - Use position_jitterdodge without a fill aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `geom_point` with `position_jitterdodge` works only when you set the fill aesthetic. I can't see why this should be!

This command

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds[ sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ], 
       aes(x = cut, y = carat, color = clarity)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, position = position_jitterdodge())
```

Produces an error:

```
Error: position_jitterdodge requires the following missing aesthetics: fill
```

This works, though:

```
ggplot(diamonds[ sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ], 
       aes(x = cut, y = carat, fill = clarity)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, position = position_jitterdodge())
```

[image]

Simply supplying a NA value to fill isn't a viable workaround:

```
ggplot(diamonds[ sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ], 
       aes(x = cut, y = carat, color = clarity, fill=NA)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, position = position_jitterdodge())

> Error in seq.default(h[1], h[2], length = n) : 
  'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
```

Although it works if you specify an arbitrary constant (forgive the hideous results):

```
ggplot(diamonds[ sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ], 
       aes(x = cut, y = carat, color = clarity, fill='constant')) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, position = position_jitterdodge())
```

[image]

Any ideas on how to use jitter/dodge without specifying fill? (i.e. colored points only)

Edit: further to @joran's comment, I'd like to overlay points over boxplots. Since one isn't necessarily going to use `fill` to differentiate boxplots, it would be great if `geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge())` accommodated plots without `fill`. Maybe not currently possible, though...

```
#This doesn't work:
ggplot(diamonds[ sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ], 
       aes(x = cut, y = carat, color = clarity)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(shape = 21, position = position_jitterdodge())

#This does, although obviously no one wants a plot like this
ggplot(diamonds[ sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ], 
       aes(x = cut, y = carat, color = clarity, fill='constant')) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(shape = 21, position = position_jitterdodge())

#This is way it's intended to work, but marries you to 'fill'
ggplot(diamonds[ sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ], 
       aes(x = cut, y = carat, fill = clarity)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(shape = 21, position = position_jitterdodge())
```

Comment: It is not a bug. The origins of this _feature_ was the specific need to place points on top of dodged box plots which have been dodged via `fill` (which is clearly referenced in the documentation at `?position_jitterdodge`). I agree it would be nice if it worked without the box plots, but this is just an unanticipated use case, not a bug.

Comment: Actually, overlaying on boxplots is exactly what I'm aiming to do, though in my case the boxplots have been dodged by color. I omitted this from the minimal example above bc it didn't seem relevant, but I'll add it back.

Comment: I can get it to work by forking ggplot2 and simply editing `position_jitterdodge` to use to use `colour` rather than fill. But I'm not sure how you'd write that function (at least, how to write it well) to handle either case.

Comment: Thank you. A hacky solution that's working for me now is to use `fill` and `color` then just `NA`-out the fill later

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, here's my workaround. Specify `fill` along with the aesthetic you really want (`color` in my case), then blank out fill with `scale_fill_manual`

I produced a different fake dataset that's more similar to my actual use case, since the diamonds data as specified above isn't really a good candidate for box + points

```
my_dat <- data.frame(class=factor(rep(1:2, 600)),
                     y=rnorm(1200)),
                     x=rep(letters[1:3], each=400))

ggplot(my_dat, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=class, color=class)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, alpha = 0.5, position=position_jitterdodge()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rep(NA, 2))
```

[image]

Comment: This was genius. I struggled with coordinating boxplot dodge + jitters for 2 days in a row!